# Why Apple is not bringing support to check whether a connection has active internet connection?

Tags: ios, reachability

When I checked the apple Reachability class, it does return true even though the connected network doesn't have an active internet connection. So I'm having few doubts here  -

1. Why is Reachability class made to throw YES if the packet can leave the local device even though it doesn't ensure it is delivered at the endpoint? Are there any special reasons to limit the ability?
2. Reachability has *reachabilityWithHostName* method still, YES will be thrown by class even if we add familiar hostname in the same network. If it doesn't ensure endpoint packet delivery why they provided this method?
3. Is there any other way to check whether there is an active internet connection in the connected network other than Reachability? Do we need to add our custom APIs or logic to tackle this thing?

I did connect an android phone to the same network, it instantaneously notified me the connection has no internet connection.

Comment: I think Apples Reachablity is out-dated. You could give AFNetworking a try: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: AFNetworking is a lot of code to pull in if all you're doing is checking reachability. I have used ReachabilitySwift with success: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift as well as there are other libraries out there for just checking reachability.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasOetjen and sklader , I think both use SCNetworkReachability API to test their network capability (correct me if I'm wrong), but it already mentioned in [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachability-g7d?changes=_4] this will also return true.  Have u guys got network is not reachable if you connect to no internet connection network by using the mentioned libraries? Of course, I use AFNetworkig btw.

Comment: AFNetworking has its own reachability functionality. You can use it if you already have AFNetworking pulled in. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager

Comment: The problem with reachability is that it just checks to see if it can connect to the specified host and many hotspot captive portals respond to any hostname and reachability is "fooled". A better test is to retrieve a known piece of content. E.g. http://captive.apple.com returns "success". This is what iOS uses to determine that it needs to display the captive portal login window

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11. Could you please elaborate your testing with captive.apple.com , as this one returns an HTML file. How this can be integrated to my project?

Comment: If reachability says that you are connected to the internet you need to,periodically fetch captive.apple.commsnd check the result for "success"if you get some other data then you are probably getting a hotspot login. Wait and try again later. Repeat until you get "success" then you know you really are connected to the internet

Comment: @Paulw11Thanks for the reply. Could you please answer my second question?